# HTML5 Itunes drag drop app look alike

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, html

I want to make custom **WEBSITE** menu that **looks like** Itunes when moving apps in iphone
(something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySx-rLJ0Ng0).
basically I'll have 1 list as source and 1 grid as destination, but the grid will have paging or grouping per 20 items.

so far I've using c# asp.net HTML5 and Jquery to create but I can't make the grouping or the paging (I used the method of sortable list but I modified the css to grid from this source http[:]//farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/).

Do you have any Idea how to make it?

I draw what I want to make in here
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/whatiwant.png/

Just like I said, I have 1 grid  that have maximum capacity 20 items per page, and 1 list to populate the grid. All I want to have is when I put more than 20 items in the grid, the grid will show new page to put the item

right now I used HTML5 and jquery, here is my code:

```
<section id="demos">
    <style>
        #demos section {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .sortable {
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .sortable.grid {
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 500px;
            background-image:url('Images/background.png');
            background-repeat:repeat-y;
        }
        .sortable li {
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            background: #F6F6F6;
            color: #1C94C4;
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            height: 22px;
        }
        .sortable.grid li {
            line-height: 80px;
            float: left;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size:x-small;
        }
        .handle {
            cursor: move;
        }
        .sortable.connected {

            min-height: 100px;
            float: left;
        }
        li.disabled {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        li.highlight {
            background: #FEE25F;
        }
        li.sortable-placeholder {
            border: 1px dashed #CCC;
            background: none;
        }
    </style>

    <section>
        <h1>Connected Sortable Lists</h1>
        <ul id="sortable4" class="connected sortable grid">
                        <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
               </ul>
        <table style="display: block; height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ul id="sortable5" class="connected sortable list">
            <li class="highlight">Item A</li>
            <li class="highlight">Item B</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
```

I just have no Idea how to make pagging in my grid.

Thank you

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific, where did you reach, what do you have so far ? Narrow it down a little bit.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov actually I just want to have a grid with pagging, and a list. so I could move item from my list to the grid and vice versa.

So far I used HTML5 from the sample '
 <section>
  <h1>Connected Sortable Lists</h1>
  <ul id="sortable4" class="connected sortable grid">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sortable5" class="connected sortable list">
   <li class="highlight">Item 1</li>
   <li class="highlight">Item 2</li>
   <li class="highlight">Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </section>
'

Comment: Done.
I used the jquery paginate to page my grid.
Thank you all